# <View> code not making changes. not appearing View

Tags: android, xml, view, line, show

`<View>`is not showing, it is not making any change.
`<View>` is tag not working.
I set a color but again its not working,
Why this is hidden?
What should I do?
Please help me....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity">

    <View android:id="@+id/view"
          android:layout_width="1dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[doesn't showing ... code's effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv687.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below code for View;

```
        <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: ThankYou Vishal....
My code was also right, but my emulator had issue.
when i choose another emulator then it works properly